# Java runtime subtype constructor call

Tags: java, constructor, casting, runtime

I have a Super class and some Sub class that extend the super class. Every sub class have some constructor methods that accept a type of any Sub type.

```
abstract class Super {}
    final class Sub1 extends Super {
        public Sub1(Sub1 arg) {}
        //...
        public Sub1(Sub4 arg) {}
    }
    //...
    final class SubN extends Super {
        public SubN(Sub3 arg) {}
        //...
        public SubN(SubN arg) {}
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a method in the Super class to cast from one Sub type to another. Let's say

```
public Super cast(Super arg) {
    if (arg instanceof Sub1)  {
        return new Sub1(this);
    } else if (arg instanceof Sub2) {
        return new Sub2(this);
    }//...
    return null;
}
```

It would be stupid to repeat this pattern for all the sub classes. A solution that I found out is this one (using reflection) but is too slow.

```
public Super cast(Super arg) {
    try {
        Class<? extends Super> type = arg.getClass();
        return type.getConstructor(this.getClass()).newInstance(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Are there alternatives?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Your `cast` method doesn't really cast.

Comment: I want to create the method cast in the Super class without repeating the pattern described above.

Comment: I know it doesn't really cast :)
What I want is the last code but without reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do the reverse? Instead of `super.cast(sub)` do `sub.copy(super)` Example:

```
class Sub1 extends Super {
    public Super copy(Super input) {
        return new Sub1(input);
    }
}

class Sub2 extends Super {
    public Super copy(Super input) {
        return new Sub2(input);
    }
}
```

etc.

This is called in nearly the same way and prevents having *any* if statements, and gets exactly the same functionality.

If your old code was:

```
void doSomething(Super super, Super iAmActuallyASub) {
    Super superDuper = super.cast(iAmActuallyASub);
}
```

The new code would be

```
void doSomething(Super super, Super iAmActuallyASub) {
    Super superDuper = iAmActuallyASub.copy(super);
}
```